# How can I create a linnet object starting from an sf object with LINESTRING geometry column?

Tags: r, r-sf, spatstat

At the moment I'm working on a project with point pattern events on a linear network (car crashes) and I'm reading chapter 17 of `spatstat` book: "Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R".

The authors of the book explain that they defined a new class of objects called `lpp` for analyzing point patterns on a linear network. The skeleton of each `lpp` object is a `linnet` object and there are several functions to create a `linnet` object. For my application the relevant functions are `linnet` and `as.linnet`. The function `linnet` creates a linear network object from the spatial location of each vertex and information about which vertices are joined by an edge, while the `as.linnet` function can be applied to a `psp` object which is transformed into `linnet` objects inferring the connectivity of the network using a specified distance threshold.

The reason why I'm asking this question is that I don't know how to efficiently create a linnet object starting from a `sf` object with a `LINESTRING` geometry. As far as I know, it's possible to transform the `sf` object into an `sp` object (i.e. a `SpatialLines` object), then I can transform the `sp` object into a `psp` object (using `as.psp` function) and then I can transform the `psp` object into a linnet object using the `as.psp.linnet` function (which is defined in the maptools package). The main problem with this approach (as the authors of the package said in their book) is that the inferred network is wrong every time an overpass or an underpass occurs in my network data since the corresponding linnet will create artificial intersections in the nework. Moreover, as the authors said in their book, the code gets exponentially slower.

The following code is a simplified version of what I did so far but I think that there must be an easier and better way to create a linnet object from an `sf` object. I would use the `linnet` function but the problem is that I don't know how to create a (sparse) adjacency matrix for the corresponding vertices of the network or a matrix of links between the edges of the network.

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.61-0       (nickname: 'Puppy zoomies') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
#> 
#> Note: spatstat version 1.61-0 is out of date by more than 11 weeks; a newer version should be available.
library(maptools)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright


# download data
iow_polygon <- getbb("Isle of Wight, South East, England", format_out = "sf_polygon", featuretype = "state") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 27700)
iow_highways <- st_read("https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/isle-of-wight-latest.osm.pbf", layer = "lines") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 27700)
#> Reading layer `lines' from data source `https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/isle-of-wight-latest.osm.pbf' using driver `OSM'
#> Simple feature collection with 44800 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -5.716262 ymin: 43.35489 xmax: 1.92832 ymax: 51.16517
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

# subset the data otherwise the code takes ages
iow_highways <- iow_highways[iow_polygon, ] %>% 
  subset(grepl(pattern = c("primary|secondary|tertiary"), x = highway))

# transform as sp 
iow_highways_sp <- as(iow_highways %>% st_geometry(), "Spatial")

# transform as psp
iow_highways_psp <- as.psp(iow_highways_sp)

# transform as linnet
iow_highways_linnet <- as.linnet.psp(iow_highways_psp, sparse = TRUE)
```

I can extract the coordinates of each vertex of the network

```r
stplanr::line2points(iow_highways)
#> Simple feature collection with 2814 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 430780.7 ymin: 75702.05 xmax: 464851.7 ymax: 96103.72
#> epsg (SRID):    27700
#> proj4string:    +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
#> First 10 features:
#>    id                  geometry
#> 1   1 POINT (464851.7 87789.73)
#> 2   1 POINT (464435.4 88250.85)
#> 3   2 POINT (464390.9 87412.27)
#> 4   2 POINT (464851.7 87789.73)
#> 5   3 POINT (462574.6 88987.62)
#> 6   3 POINT (462334.6 88709.92)
#> 7   4 POINT (464066.9 87576.84)
#> 8   4 POINT (464390.9 87412.27)
#> 9   5   POINT (464420 88227.79)
#> 10  5 POINT (464398.7 88225.33)
```

but then I don't know how to build the adjacency matrix.

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure why you go through the `psp` format on the way to `linnet`.
Try to replace the last two lines of your first code chunk by:

`iow_highways_linnet <- as.linnet.SpatialLines(iow_highways_sp)`

This converts `SpatialLines` directly to `linnet` and fuses lines
that share a vertex. I don’t think an underpass will be fused to an
overpass unless both lines have a vertex at the intersection point.
See example below:

```r
l1 <- sf::st_linestring(matrix(c(-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1), ncol = 2))
l2 <- sf::st_linestring(matrix(c(-1,-1,1,1,2,1,-1,-2), ncol = 2))
l_sf <- sf::st_sf(id = 1:2, geom = sf::st_sfc(l1,l2))
l_sp <- sf::as_Spatial(l_sf)
l <- maptools::as.linnet.SpatialLines(l_sp)
plot(l)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer. I've never used the `as.linnet.SpatialLines` function because I didn't know it existed. Anyway I just tested your approach on the IOW example and it works smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just confirming that the `spatstat` package does not provide functions for handling other formats; our expectation is that `maptools` or other packages will provide format conversion code; this is not yet available for `sf` object formats, presumably because `sf` is relatively new.

The key question is whether an `sf` object with LINESTRING geometry contains enough information to determine connectivity of the network. If so, then I suggest you make a 2-column matrix listing all pairs of vertices which are joined by edges, and invoke `spatstat::linnet`. If not, then the available data are not sufficient...

Finally please note that the current development version of `spatstat`(1.61-0.061) available from [GitHub](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat) is very much faster than the current release (1.61-0) for many operations on linear networks. It will be released publicly soon.